# For every undirected unweighted graph is every MST also a SPT

Tags: graphs

I have a feeling this might be wrong an I'm looking for a counter example, however, I couldn't find one yet.. can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: What's the definition of an MST in an unweighted graph?

Comment: Perhaps the following question and the examples given there are helpful: [Minimum spanning tree vs Shortest path](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18797/4287).

Comment: @IOX: I think you can just assume it's like a weighted graph but all edges have the same weight (or just say have weight 1). Hendrik: thanks!

Comment: if all edges have the same weight, then any tree has a weight of $w(V-1)$, which makes any tree MST. I think you meant to ask the question with a weighted graph. In which case the answer is no.

Comment: Since every tree in an unweighted graph is an MST, your question asks whether every tree is a shortest path tree. It looks like this is true if and only if the given graph is acyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter example: `V={a,b,c,d}, E={(a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (b,c)}`.
A MST of this graph, rooted at `a`, could be: `{(a,b), (a,d), (b,c)}`. But this is not a SPT because the path `a->c` is of length 2 instead of 1 (`a` and `c` are directly connected in the original graph).

Answer (score 0):

Shortest-path tree is defined for a graph and a root vertex.

Edit: My previous example was for a weighted graph, but still you can find counter-examples by choosing the root vertex carefully.

Comment: Does this make sense: I have a graph `G = (V,E)` with `V = {A,B,C}` and `E = {(A,B), (B,C), (A,C)}` and say my MST `G'` has edges `{(C,A), (C,B)}` it's not a SPT when I set the root of the SPT at `A`. Therefore not every MST is a SPT.

Comment: Seems right to me